# Swift error Trying to Pass Array to Another Class

Tags: arrays, swift, instance, member

So I am probably doing this all wrong but I want to make a shopping list app and I have two view controllers, one with the list and one with a textbook and button to add to the list but I can't figure out how to get the array to the other class. I have this code so far and  the error I get is

```
Instance member 'list' cannot be used in type 'mainViewController'
```

And this is my code

```
import UIKit

class mainViewController: UIViewController {
    var list:[String] = [""]
    @IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mainViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func AddToList(sender: UIButton) {
        list.append(item.text!)

    }

    static func getList(inout Array: [String]) -> [String] {
        return list
    }

}
```

Any help much appreciated, please keep it positive though and keep in mind I am very new to this forum and swift. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear that you are trying to access an instance field in type context (without instance).

To fix it, just remove `static` in `getList` function.

PS: Please follow Swift naming conventions to capitalize your class name

Comment: If I removed static from that function would I still be able to call that in my other class? And if I can how would I do it so I can still get the count from the array? Is there a better way to get the array to the other class?

Comment: If I removed static from that function would I still be able to call that in my other class? And if I can how would I do it so I can still get the count from the array? Is there a better way to get the array to the other class?

Comment: Please learn OOP. You need to create an instance and then call the instance method. something like `var controller = mainViewController(); controller.getList()`